# Color hue loop - SCSS

Tags: css, sass

With SASS can you iterate through the color of the hue scale for a given index? Currently I am just doing a different CSS selector for each tier. But I am trying to find an more efficient solution using SASS. But as you can see I don't really know where to start.

```
//Current code
.element[ tier="1" ] > i {
  background: #08C026;
}

//Attempted solution (fail)
@for $i from 1 through 40 {
  .element[ tier="#{$i}" ] > i {
    background: #08C026; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I want each of the 40 selectors to have a different background color value so they iterate through the hue of the first color value, Like a rainbow

Comment: Ok, so where's your list of colors?  If not a specific list of colors, how are you expecting to generate them?

Comment: So I want SASS to take this HEX value #08C026 and iterate through the HUE range. If possible?

Comment: http://boxofficequant.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Hue_Value.png - So i have given an initial value and i want SASS to iterate through the HUE range so that i get slightly different colors for each iteration

Comment: Yes, but you haven't specified how.  I get that you want different colors.  You're starting with green, which is in the middle of the rainbow, and you're expecting it to be what color by the time you get to the 40th selector?

Comment: http://sassme.arc90.com/ So I want to use adjust_hue and go from 0 to 360 by the time it gets to the 40th element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To programatically generate your colors, you need to determine how many degrees it takes to adjust the color by for your desired range and multiply that by your counter.

```
$qty: 40;
$step: 360deg / $qty;

@for $i from 0 through $qty - 1 {
    .element[ tier="#{$i}" ] > i {
        background: adjust-hue(#08C026, $step * $i);
    }
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/2a9c4f3e1a9743a11d15

Comment: How come when you change the $qty that it changes the start colour?

Comment: Even if I start it at 500, the first color is the same as the starting color?

Comment: @maioman It's not supposed to?  I only demoed with nth-child because the markup was simpler to generate.  If you want it to cycle, then I've already answered that question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469974/cycling-through-a-list-of-colors-with-sass

Comment: @cinnamon in your other answer it's an array; I was thinking about a way of resetting counter to 0 in this scenario...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $class-slug: your-selector !default

 @for $i from 0 through 39
 .#{$class-slug}-#{$i}
 adjust_hue(#00ff00, $i*9)
```

Comment: Ah nice, yeh that works. Is there anyway to work out the multiply value in a smarter way based on the through number (39 in this case)?

Comment: mmm, you could add a $step: 9 and multiply $i*$step but that doesn't change anything... what do you mean by smarter way?

Comment: I mean by using some logic. So adjust hue goes up to 360 then it repeats i believe so by 39/360 and the calculation of that sum is the multiplier to equal the spacing in the hue range?

Comment: it should be something like `counter-reset: lis $i`  but you need to try because I'm not sure, let me know; regards