# Programmatically nest rules with sass

Tags: css, sass, nested

So basically I have a list of colours and I want to change the border colour of a list in the html depending on how deep it is in the DOM.

This is the SASS that I have at the moment:

```
$colors:
    green,
    red,
    blue,
    orange,
;


.list {
    border-color:nth($C-subList-borders,1);
    .list {
        border-color:nth($C-subList-borders,2);
        .list {
            border-color:nth($C-subList-borders,3);
            .list {
                border-color:nth($C-subList-borders,4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which generates this css:

```
.list { border-color: green; }
.list .list { border-color: red; }
.list .list .list { border-color: blue; }
.list .list .list .list { border-color: orange; }
```

What I want to do be able to do is generate the .list rules based on the number of colours I have in the $colors variable rather than doing it manually. I can't figure out how though.

I know it's going to have an @each or @for loop in there but I can't figure out the syntax to make it work. I'm not sure if it's even possible.

**----- UPDATE: My Own Answer -----**

Since the question was marked as a duplicate I can't post this as an actual answer, so this will have to do. Thanks Hidden Hobbes for your answer. That gave me an idea of how the syntax should work. You had a redundant @each in your answer though so I've written this instead (I'll accept yours though since your answer gave me the inspiration)

```
$colors: green red blue orange;

$class: '.list';
$selector: $class;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    $color: nth($colors,$i);
    #{$selector} {
        border-color: $color;
    }
    $selector: $selector $class;
}
```

Comment: Not entirely convinced that this is a duplicate. While the two questions share similarities in so far they are looping and nesting lists, I think the usage of the `$colours` variable as the source of the loop makes this question different enough to not be considered as a duplicate. My answer, for example, will not be relevant in the linked question.

Comment: The fact that you're using colors instead of margins is not enough justification for this to be "not a duplicate".  How you get the number of steps is irrelevant:  there are plenty of other questions that cover how to loop over a list of items.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469974/cycling-through-a-list-of-colors-with-sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SASS code should get you the result you are after. The `@each` statement will loop through each colour. The `@for` loop is based upon the index of the colour in the list and will append the correct number of `.list` to the selector.

```
$colors: green red blue orange;

@each $color in $colors {
    $i: index($colors, $color);
    @for $c from 1 through $i {
        @if $c == 1 {
            $selector: '.list';
        } @else {
            $selector: $selector '.list';
        }
    }
    #{$selector} {
        border-color: #{$color};
    }
}
```

SASS Meister: http://sassmeister.com/gist/106687cca4d2a8ce5fc4

Comment: Glad I could help. Your answer is certainly a lot neater than my suggestion!