# Cycling through an array of colors with SASS

Tags: sass

My question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469974/cycling-through-a-list-of-colors-with-sass), but rather than using a list of colors I want to access them from an array that I already have setup for use with other color functions. E.g.

```
$chart-palette: (
  green: #39B54A,
  yellow: #FFAE00,
  red: #E6001F,
  orange: #F78200
);
```

Borrowing from the example already supplied, this is what I have thus far:

```
@for $i from 1 through length($chart-palette) {
    div:nth-child(#{length($chart-palette)}n+#{$i}) {
        background: nth($chart-palette, $i)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40468509/3909886

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.